# What are the Horizon 2.0 PostgreSQL settings required to vacuum the DB regularly

Tags: horizon

Need guidelines on how to best manage the size of the horizon captive-core postrgesql DB. We're currently at 1TB of disk for horizon DB only ingesting ledgers from June 2020.

Comment: the horizon db reached 2.5TB attempting to restore ledgers from June 2020. I give up. We are not going to run a full horizon node because frankly this is insane.